# Defining a function using the generics

Tags: javascript, typescript

Having such a simple code:

```
interface ServerData {
  foo: string
  bar: number
}

const oo = {
  foo: "abc",
  bar: 887
}

function foo<ServerData>(x: ServerData): number { return x.foo }
```

I get the error on the
last line:

```
Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'ServerData'
```

It's strange since the `ServerData` interface is already defined above. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Its because the generic type `ServerData` defined on the function might not have the property `foo` (the generic and the interface are not the same thing, you have to tell this to the compiler).

Nowhere in the code you say to the compiler that the generic has this property. In your case you could get rid of the generic entirely like this (also you would have to convert `foo` to a Number since the function returns a Number):

```
function foo(x: ServerData): number { return Number(x.foo) }
```

or you could tell the compiler that the generic type in the function implements the `ServerData` interface like this:

```
function foo<T extends ServerData>(x: T): number { return Number(x.foo) }
```

The basic problem here is that you aren't telling the compiler what this type actually is, so it doesn't know that the parameter has this property. If you want to pass a generic and tell the compiler that the property `foo` exists you can also do this:

```
function foo<T extends {foo: string}>(x: T): number { return Number(x.foo) }
```

Answer (score 1):

A complement to the answer by @WilsonPena.

In your declaration of the `foo` function `ServerData` is a local type variable; it's *not* referring to the global type/interface `ServerData`. Your declaration is actually equivalent to

```js
function foo<T>(x: T): number { return x.foo }
```

Here it's clearer that it's not known whether the object `x` has a field `foo`.

What you probably want is

```js
function foo(x: ServerData): number { return x.foo }
```

Now the type engine knows that there is a field `foo` on `x`. You will however get another error since the field `foo` in `ServerData` is a string, but you has declared that the function `foo` returns a number.